# Argument of type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormControl'

Tags: angular, angular9

After migration to angular 9 from angular 8, get this error

> ERROR in app/src/app/users/add/add.component.html:14:48 - error
>   NG2345: Argument of type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'FormControl'.   Type 'AbstractControl' is missing
>   the following properties from type 'FormControl': registerOnChange,
>   registerOnDisabledChange, _applyFormState

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let error of errors(addNewUserForm.get('username'))">
```

Here is my function

```
errors(ctrl: FormControl): string[] {
   return ctrl.errors ? Object.keys(ctrl.errors) : [];
}
```

In angular 8 everything is working. Thnx

Comment: change errors method ctrl type to AbstractControl

Answer (score 0):

I used $any() to work around this. It is weird that it is complaining about it since `export declare class FormControl extends AbstractControl`.

Answer (score 0):

I have to same problem, changing `FormControl` to `AbstractControl` solves my problem. This [article](https://indepth.dev/posts/1143/a-thorough-exploration-of-angular-forms) explains in detail about Angular Forms, FormControl and AbstractControl.

```js
errors(ctrl: AbstractControl): string[] {
   return ctrl.errors ? Object.keys(ctrl.errors) : [];
}
```